# NetworkManager-pptp SSTP VPN access with EAP enabled?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, ubuntu-20.04, networkmanager

I'm trying to connect to my work VPN. They recently changed to SSTP with EAP-MSCHAPv2 and I can't get it working on Ubuntu.

In Network Manager VPN advanced setup, EAP is unselectable as an authentication method.

[(Screenshot)EAP is grayed out and unselectable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTXT3.png)

If I edit the connection manually in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections and remove/comment out refuse-eap=yes it doesn't do anything and EAP is still unselected in Network Manager.

That is the first time I'm posting here because i couldn't find anyone else having the same issue. Hope it gets answered :)

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: I see the same problem with 18.04

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a PPTP connection instead of SSTP, this allow you to enable also EAP.

Comment: I can select EAP when creating the connection, but next time I edit it, it is greyed out. 
BUT, can You connect to a SSTP server using PPTP?
I had no luck with trying PPTP.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck `Use Point-to-Point Encryption (MPPE)` and `PAP`, `CHAP`, and `EAP` will be clickable again.